# Need issue tracker, for general use, not only software

Tags: tracking, issue-tracking

I'm looking for a free or commercial issue tracker. I've looked at a dozen of them, but I can't find what I need.

These are my requirements:

- Not only for software. I need a more general tracker in which "complaints" about products other than software can also be recorded.
- Very easy to use, for non-technical users
- (optional) rich text editing, possibility to add images between the lines, etc.

I've looked at Bugzilla, SupportSuite, Mantis, but these are to much software oriented for my case.

Comment: Probably http://programmers.stackexchange.com is a better place for this question.

Comment: What makes an issue tracker unsuitable for general complaints about products?

Answer (score 5):

Strange, no-one mentioned `Trello` [ [www.trello.com](http://www.trello.com) ]

Its :

- General purpose
- Software related tracking can also be done
- Collaboration on anything with multiple people
- Free to use [ Even for multiple users ]
- Aimed at a non-technical user

Perfect for your use-case.

Answer (score 4):

Or take a loot at [Gemini](http://countersoft.com) -- we have IT hardware, Help Desk and all our software dev projects in one place. Gemini does allow for different "meta data" per project type so this works for us. Look at their "white paper" - may be of help to you in terms of set up.

Comment: I should have also said -- you can totally change all on-screen taxonomy to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the commercial ones are more polished than the open-source ones, here are some options:

- [Atlassian JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) - an industry veteran, very complete solution. If you have a small team (up to 5 people), they also used to have a very low-cost version.
- [JetBrains YouTrack](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) - relative newcomer, an probably a bit too "keyboard-centric" for your needs.

See also [comparison of issue-tracking systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Both appear to be really aimed toward software development. I like to avoid words like "bugs" and "hardware platform", which will scare the non-technical users. I'm starting wonder if such software even exists..

Comment: As far as I know, JIRA should be very customizable in terms of terminology and field names. I suggest you download a trial and see if it is possible to configure it to fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for a service like http://getsatisfaction.com/ or http://uservoice.com/. They are very customer-centric, and I've seen them used both for software products and for feedback on other things entirely.

Also, I've made Mantis receive email directly both to new and existing issues - f.ex. if subject contains an issue number like [1234] the email becomes a note to the issue 1234.

This way the customer doesn't know about Mantis, you can bcc Mantis with issue numbers, and it's possible to customize workflow in Mantis very much to suit your process needs.

In addition, you can have separate projects in Mantis which can receive from different email addresses, like one for bugs and one for support issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/), am not sure whether it is free or what.

Or you may try with googling JIRA